# Registering a “typed” gRPC client with the ASP.NET Core DI container

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, grpc

I have a GrpcService class the takes in gRPC client in its constructor, like so:

```
public class GrpcService : IService 
{
    private readonly GrpcClient grpcClient;
 
    public GrpcService(GrpcClient grpcClient)
    {
        this.grpcClient = grpcClient;
    }
    
    //...
}
```

I have registered the gRPC client in the Startup class by using the generic AddGrpcClient extension method:

```
services.AddGrpcClient<GrpcClient>(o =>
{
    o.Address = new Uri("https://localhost:5001");
});
```

Now I want to inject the GrpcService class into a API controller. My question is; what's is the correct way to register the GrpcService in the Startup class?

I did try the following, which did not work:

```
services.AddGrpcClient<GrpcService>();
```

At the moment I have the following code, which works fine:

```
services.AddSingleton<IService, GrpcService>();
```

However, I'm not certain using a singleton is the correct lifetime to use, in particular as the gRPC client uses HttpClient internally?

Answer (score 0):

[According to MS docs, that would be a singleton.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/client?view=aspnetcore-5.0#client-performance)

[What you're looking for is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/clientfactory?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

If you change `services.AddGrpcClient<GrpcService>();` to `services.AddGrpcClient<GrpcClient>();` and inject `GrpcClient` in your consumer constructor it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).